# imageLoad() behavior for non-existent texel

Tags: opengl, glsl, vulkan, image-load-store

Is there a way to influence the behavior of `imageLoad()` for accessing an `image2D` or `uimage2D` with an out-of-bounds texel coordinate; for example repeat the last *good* texel instead of returning 0s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. When you use image load/store, you don't get to play "texture" games like playing with the border color, doing filtering on values, etc. You are fetching a texel from a particular location.

If you want this, you will have to detect the out-of-bounds access and choose to substitute an alternate value. You can query the image's size, so it should be easy enough to detect.